# fastest nosql for a single counter

Tags: mongodb, redis, nosql

Mongodb has objectid as default primary key
This provides good scalability, but url's is awful
I prefer simple ID's in url. Plus it is much reliable to put int() at very case very ID of anything should be received

So the idea is following:
Before any object saved via mongodb a call to another nosql made to receive global counter
The call should be atomic and return int

Redis's INC is exactly fits the requirement
The question is... is redis realy best solution?
Maybe some other nosql will make simple one-counter-increment from multiply clients faster then redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can store this incrementing numeric key in MongoDB itself, in a single document collection, as something like `{ "_id": 1, "currentKey": 99 }`.

Use the [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command to atomically increment and retrieve the `currentKey` value.

It might be best to keep the MongoDB ObjectId value as your `_id`, and store this numeric key in a separate uniquely indexed field to use for URL lookups.  This way, if down the line you want to scale out you'll be better prepared.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own ids for mongodb, there is such an option. But then you will have to deal with uniqueness. Why do you want to use another nosql for this? I see it pointless, you can gerenate your own unique keys, if you can, and use with mongo.

Redis INC is used for counters, if you look at that functionality, mongodb has a $inc operator as well, that you can use as a counter. But that s not the purpose of this operator. These are mostly used for analytics etc.

Comment: Thats a problem, while using $inc(it is for sure slower then redis) i can have problem, that different servers generate same counter, so no uniqness across server. With global id-maker on redis uniqness is guranteed. The puprose is unique id for all objects. Whatever they are. Users, posts, comments. I dont see better solution to remove objectid from url, while being generic. So question is what nosql is best for it

Comment: but you dont use $inc operator to generate object ids. let mongodb create the ids for you, if you want, and you HAVE to change the URL looks, make something like youtube or bitly urls. which are a mapper. you are introducing extra layers with redis etc. dont do that.

Comment: The mapper has same problem, it should be unique and something should take care of it, keeping in mind that this something should keep it unique across servers. So it also will be additional layer. They just use hex instead of int. And what benefit of keeping two unique values, one is mongodb id, and another one mapper unique id?

Comment: security is the benefit. mapper doesnt have the same problem. yes you can make the mapper to be unique, if you have the odjids, servers and collections. what if your redis instance(s) goes down? then what will you do?